# Mysql update query works without using parameters but doesn't when using them

Tags: c#, mysql

Good day,

In c#, I am trying to run a MySQL update query to update one record, based on its id. Everything goes well as long as I'm not using parameters.

I'm experiencing the issue once I am adding one or several parameters. I have made the test with only one parameter and same problem here.

What am I missing here ?

Thank you very much for your help.

```
    public static void editCustomerTest(ClsCustomerTest pTest)
    {
        MySqlConnection l_Connection = null;
        string l_SpName = string.Empty;
        MySqlCommand l_MyCommand = null;

        try
        {
            l_Connection = ClsIconEnv.getDataAccess().MySqlConnection;

            ClsDataAccess.OpenConnection(l_Connection);

            l_SpName = "update tbTestCustomers " +
                    "set sName = '@sLastName', " +
                    "sFirstName = '@sFirstName', " +
                    "sAddress = '@sAddress' " +
                    "Where id = @id);";
            l_MyCommand = new MySqlCommand(l_SpName, l_Connection);

            l_MyCommand.Parameters.Add("@sLastName", pTest.Last_Name);
            l_MyCommand.Parameters.Add("@sFirstName", pTest.First_name);
            l_MyCommand.Parameters.Add("@sAddress", pTest.Address);
            l_MyCommand.Parameters.Add("@id", pTest.id);

            l_MyCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(); // <----- This is the line at which the execution stops

            ClsDataAccess.CloseConnection(l_Connection);
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            ClsIconErrorManager.manageException(exc);
        }
        finally
        {
        }
    }
```

Comment: get rid of the ticks around the parameter placeholders (all of them)

Comment: @ŇɏssaPøngjǣrdenlarp: thank you, but not sure to get what you mean. Do you mean this ' character ?

Comment: As well as the ticks, none of the overrides for [`MySqlParameterCollection.Add()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/8.0/html/T_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlParameterCollection.htm) accept arguments that are `Add(ParameterName, ParameterValue`), you should either use [`AddwithValue()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/8.0/html/M_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlParameterCollection_AddWithValue.htm), or one of the valid overrides for `Add()` then assign the value, e.g. `l_MyCommand.Parameters.Add("@id", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = pTest.id;`

Comment: I think you mean to use AddWithValue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to wrap your params into the string and you have to use `AddWithValue` instead of `Add` if you don't want to explicitly specify the type, like this

```
l_SpName = "update tbTestCustomers " +
"set sName = @sLastName, " +
"sFirstName = @sFirstName, " +
"sAddress = @sAddress" +
"Where id = @id);";


l_MyCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sLastName", pTest.Last_Name);
l_MyCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sFirstName", pTest.First_name);
l_MyCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sAddress", pTest.Address);
l_MyCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", pTest.id);
```

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
        l_SpName = @"update tbTestCustomers 
                set sName = @sLastName, 
                sFirstName = @sFirstName, 
                sAddress = @sAddress 
                Where id = @id";
        l_MyCommand = new MySqlCommand(l_SpName, l_Connection);

        l_MyCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sLastName", pTest.Last_Name);
        l_MyCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sFirstName", pTest.First_name);
        l_MyCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sAddress", pTest.Address);
        l_MyCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", pTest.id);

        l_MyCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: SO syntax highlighter doesn't like that @string much, but it's a valid and reasonable way to tidy up SQL strings dumped into C# - all the `"+"` gets a bit much..